# Maclaurin series of $\ln \left( 1+\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x} \right)$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

So the first thing I done was
$$\begin{align}\ln(1+x)&=x-\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{3}x^3+o(x^3)\\&=(1+x)\left(x-\frac{3}{2}x^2+\frac{11}{6}x^3\right)+o(x^3)\end{align}$$

I've never seen this done but I'm pretty sure I can do this.

Now I want to divide:

$$(1+x)\left(x-\frac{3}{2}x^2+\frac{11}{6}x^3\right)+o(x^3)$$By $(1+x)$ but I don't know what
$\frac{o(x^3)}{1+x}$ will be.

Also is there another way to do this?

Comment: Hello. Use backslashes for functions: `\ln,\sin,\cos` and so on. I also used the `\begin{align}\end{align}` command (to centre equations as needed), as well as the `\left(\right)` commands (which make brackets bigger according to your needs) to improve on your formatting. Give it a good look

Comment: @FShrike it was  $(1+x)(x-3/2x^2+11/6x^3) +o(x^3)$ before you edited it , can you edit it again? When I try to do it I get lost in the code you wrote

Comment: Ah apologies I misinterpreted, I'll fix that

Comment: Note:
$$ \frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x} = \sum_n \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \sum_m (-1)^m x^m = \sum_n \sum_m \frac{(-1)^m}{n+1}x^{n+m+1} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{k-m} x^k $$

Comment: Can you elaborate ?

Comment: The above is the Maclaurin series for your argument. Ah but I have typo. The $\sum$ for $m$ should range from $ m= 0$ to $m = k-1$

Comment: @Gregory There is no nice way to composite that with another $\ln$, right? It is still not easy for Jurgen to manage with $$\ln\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^{k-1}\frac{(-1)^m}{k-m}x^k\right)$$Unless I am missing something

Comment: Jurgen: What makes you think this problem is tractable? I.e. were you just curious or did you get set this as an exercise

Comment: The problem was at the exam few years back. There is a limit that needs to be evaluated using taylor expansion and the problem in my question is the numerator of that limit

Comment: Maybe showing the whole limit will be useful - you may not need the full Maclaurin expansion (e.g. computing the first few terms is straightforward - I got stuck trying to do the entire series)

Comment: That is what I'm trying to do,  I need first 3 terms  which I got( and they fit nicely) but I get o(x^3)/x+1 and I don't know what to do with it

Comment: The first three terms are computable by hand: the derivatives are $1,-4,22$ in order first, second, third

Comment: That didn't even cross my mind lol, but now I'm generally curious why is o(x^3)/x+1 = o(x^3) because I just checked on wolfram alpha and all coefficients in the expansion of ln(1+x)/(1+x) are same as the ones I got with the method in my question. Anyways thanks for your help I appreciate you spending several hours trying to help me

Comment: Let $f(x)\in o(x^3),\,x\to 0$. Then $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{1+x}\cdot\frac{1}{x^3}=\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x+1}\right)\cdot\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x^3}\right)=1\cdot0=0$$So $$\frac{f(x)}{x+1}\in o(x^3),\,x\to0$$As well

Comment: Wolfy says $x - 2 x^2 + (11 x^3)/3 - (163 x^4)/24 + (129 x^5)/10 + O(x^6)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @jjagmaths approach we show
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\ln\left(1+\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\right)}
&\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{1}{m}
\sum_{{k_1+\cdots +k_m=n}\atop{k_1,\ldots,k_m\geq 1}}H_{k_1}\cdots H_{k_m}x^n}\tag{1}\\
&=x-2x^2+\frac{11}{3}x^3\color{blue}{-\frac{163}{24}}x^4+\cdots
\end{align*}

> Denoting with $[x^n]$ the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series we obtain for $n\geq 1$:
> \begin{align*}
> [x^n]&\ln\left(1+\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\right)\\
> &=\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{m}[x^n]\frac{\ln^m(1+x)}{(1+x)^m}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

In (2) we note that since $\ln(1+x)$ starts with $x$, the $m$-th power of $\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}$ starts with $x^m$ and we can restrict the sum with the upper limit $n$. We have
\begin{align*}
A(x)&=\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\\
&=\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}x^k\right)\left(\sum_{l=0}^\infty(-1)^lx^l\right)\\
&=\sum_{q=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{{k+l=q}\atop{k\geq 1, l\geq 0}}\frac{(-1)^{k-1+l}}{k}\right)x^q\\
&=\sum_{q=1}^\infty(-1)^{q-1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^q\frac{1}{k}\right)x^q\\
&=\sum_{q=1}^\infty(-1)^{q-1}H_qx^q\\
\end{align*}
It follows for $m\geq 1$:
\begin{align*}
A^m(x)&=\sum_{q=m}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{{k_1+\cdots+k_m=q}\atop{k_1,\ldots,k_m\geq 1}}
(-1)^{k_1-1}H_{k_1}\cdots(-1)^{k_m-1}H_{k_m}\right)x^q\\
&=\sum_{q=m}^{\infty}(-1)^{q-m}\sum_{{k_1+\cdots+k_m=q}\atop{k_1,\ldots,k_m\geq 1}}
H_{k_1}\cdots H_{k_m}x^q\\
\end{align*}
and for $n\geq m$:
\begin{align*}
[x^n]A^m(x)&=(-1)^{n-m}\sum_{{k_1+\cdots+k_m=n}\atop{k_1,\ldots,k_m\geq 1}}
H_{k_1}\cdots H_{k_m}\tag{3}
\end{align*}

> Putting (3) in (2) we obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^n]\ln\left(1+\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\right)
> =\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{m}\sum_{{k_1+\cdots+k_m=n}\atop{k_1,\ldots,k_m\geq 1}}
> H_{k_1}\cdots H_{k_m}}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (1) follows.

Calculating for instance the coefficient of $x^4$ we obtain from (4)
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{[x^4]}&\color{blue}{\ln\left(1+\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\right)}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{4}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{m}\sum_{{k_1+\cdots+k_m=4}\atop{k_1,\ldots,k_m\geq 1}}
H_{k_1}\cdots H_{k_m}\\
&=-\left(H_4+\frac{1}{2}\left(2H_1H_3+H_2^2\right)+\frac{1}{3}\left(3H_1^2H_2\right)+\frac{1}{4}H_1^4\right)\\
&=-\left(\frac{25}{12}+\frac{1}{2}\left(2\cdot 1\cdot \frac{11}{6}+\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2\right)+\frac{1}{3}\left(3\cdot 1\cdot\frac{3}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{4}\cdot 1\right)\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=-\frac{163}{24}}
\end{align*}
in accordance with the claim (1) and Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Very well done! And a very elegant perspective too. I spent around an hour attempting to do this by calculating derivatives of the form $x^n\ln^m(1+x)$ and summing them all up

Comment: @FShrike: Many thanks for your nice comment and the credit. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Right now I don't have time to post the complete solution, but the series is:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\left(\sum_{k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_m=n}\frac{1}{m}H_{k_1}H_{k_2}\cdots H_{k_m}\right)x^n$$

where $H_k$ is the $k$-th harmonic number and the inner sum is taken over all the possible ways of writing $n$ as a sum of positive integers.

Comment: It seems an inner sum is missing. Nevertheless (+1).

Comment: @epi163sqrt No inner sum is missing. Take for example the coefficient of $x^4$. You'll have $$(-1)^{4+1}\sum_{k_1+k_2+\cdots + k_m= 4} \frac{1}{m}H_{k_1}H_{k_2}\cdots H_{k_m} $$ The sum will have the summands corresponding to the [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of $4$: $4$, $1+3$, $2+2$, $3+1$, $1+1+2$, $1+2+1$, $2+1+1$, $1+1+1+1$, which gives $$\frac{1}{1}H_4+\frac{1}{2}H_1H_3+\frac{1}{2}H_2H_2+\frac{1}{2}H_3H_1+\frac{1}{3}H_1H_1H_2+\frac{1}{3}H_1H_2H_1+\frac{1}{3}H_2H_1H_1+\frac{1}{4}H_1H_1H_1H_1 = \frac{163}{24}$$ which is the same answer you got.

Comment: The inner sum respects the index region $1\leq m\leq 4$ for the number $m$ of summands $k_j$ with $1\leq j\leq m$.

Comment: Yes, $$\sum_{m=1}^n \sum_{k_1 + k_2 \cdots + k_m = n} \cdots =\sum_{k_1 + k_2 \cdots + k_m = n} \cdots$$ I feel there's no need to split the sum according to the number of summands $k_i$. The way I wrote it is more concise and represent the same sum.

Comment: Yes, I see your point, it's a matter of taste. I sometimes write bound index variables like $m$ explicitly by a sum. In fact it comes naturally from my derivation.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=1+x$ and $w=u+\log(u$).  Rewrite
$$
f(x)=\log(1+\frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x})=\log(w) -\log(u)
$$
We seek the coefficients in the Taylor series expansion
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f^{\{n\}}(0)\frac{x^n}{n!}
$$
where the coefficient $f^{\{n\}}(0)$ is the nth derivative of the function evaluated at $x=0$. We find
$$
f^{'}(x)=\frac{w^{'}}{w}-\frac{1}{u}
$$
$$
f^{"}(x)=\frac{w^{"}}{w}-\frac{w^{'}}{w^2} +\frac{1}{u^2}
$$
$$
f^{\{3\}}(x)=\frac{w^{\{3\}}}{w}-\frac{2w^{"}}{w^2} +\frac{2w^{'}}{w^3}-\frac{2}{u^3}
$$
$$
f^{\{4\}}(x)=\frac{w^{\{4\}}}{w}- \frac{3w^{\{3\}}}{w^2}+\frac{6w^{"}}{w^3} -\frac{6w^{'}}{w^4}+\frac{6}{u^4}
$$
$$
f^{\{5\}}(x)=\frac{w^{\{5\}}}{w}- \frac{4w^{\{4\}}}{w^2}+\frac{12w^{\{3\}}}{w^3} -\frac{24w^{"}}{w^4}+\frac{24w^{'}}{w^5}-\frac{24}{u^5}
$$
We now observe
$$
w(0)=1\\
w^{'}(0)=2\\
w^{"}(0)=-1\\
w^{\{3\}}(0)=2\\
w^{\{4\}}(0)=-6=-3!\\
w^{\{5\}}(0)=24=4!
$$
Plugging these values into our derivative equations we find by induction,
$$
f(0)=0\\
f^{'}(0)=1\\
f^{"}(0)=-2\\
f^{\{3\}}(0)=6=3!\\
f^{\{4\}}(0)=-24=-4!\\
f^{\{5\}}(0)=5!\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
f^{\{n\}}(0)= (-1)^{n+1}n!\\
$$
Thus, interestingly enough,
$$
\log(1+\frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x})=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}x^n
$$

Comment: The right hand side is $\frac{x}{1+x}$ for $|x|<1$.

Comment: Yes, I attempted a similar expansion myself F.Wright - I obtained maybe three different candidate series, all of which were hopelessly wrong.. including this $(-1)^{n+1}x^n$ thing. The derivatives of the desired function actually blow up quite significantly